# Terraform - create and pass files between modules in loop

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules, terraform-provider-kubernetes, terraform-provider-gitlab

My TF scripts are creating k8s resources and generating kubeconfig files based on `template_file`.
Which I then want to pass to another module (that uses GitLab provider - to save them as GitLab variables).

Up until now I was creating only one kubconfig and the approach was quite straightforward:

```
data "template_file" "kubeconfig_template" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/kubeconfig.tpl")}"
  vars     = {...}
}

output "kubeconfig" {
  value = data.template_file.kubeconfig_template.rendered
}
```

and then passing to GitLab module with:

```
module "gitlab" {
  source = "./gitlab"
  kubeconfig = module.kubernetes.kubeconfig
}
```

and using as:

```
resource "gitlab_group_variable" "kubeconfig_var" {
  value     = base64encode(var.kubeconfig)
  ...
}
```

#### But how to achieve the same for more than one file?

I see that `count` works also on data, so I can define:

```
data "template_file" "kubeconfig_templates" {
  count    = length(var.namespaces)
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/kubeconfig.tpl")}"
  vars     = {...}
}
```

but then `output` doesn't support `count`, and my "fancy" workaround with forced loop doesn't seem to be working:

```
output "kubeconfigs" {
  value = [
     for namespace in var.namespaces :
     data.template_file.kubeconfig_templates[index(var.namespaces, namespace)].rendered
  ]
}
```

Do you have any idea how to approach such a topic?

Comment: I was looking also into the `fileset()`, but then probably there may be a dependency issue? (Trying to create the variables in GitLab module before the files are created in Terraform module).

Comment: Can I ask why you're storing the rendered files as GitLab variables instead of storing them as artifacts? That feels like an anti-pattern, since you may have multiple terraform pipelines running at once and that could cause your variables to be overwritten, causing a race condition.

Comment: The rendered files are kubeconfigs that are used later on in generated project/service-specific pipelines, therefore having them as GitLab CI/CD vars let me manage and reference them there conveniently. I'm not sure what artifacts did you mean, but the job artifacts don't seem suitable for that, actually, I think that vars are the intended solution for such case, and race condition doesn't seem possible (for my particular scenario).

Comment: It sounds like you're creating a yml file (your rendered config) which you're using in a downstream job (presumably for deploying to k8s). I would recommend you use the `local_file` resource to save your rendered output to a local file, which you then store as an artifact. When your downstream job then needs to deploy to k8s, you pull that artifact and run it. Using variables with your project will cause every pipeline that you run to use those variables - passing values between jobs/pipelines that way is very likely not the intended use, as configs would bleed between pipelines.

Comment: I'm not sure we're clear on my case. Or I'm missing something.
I do want the generated files to be GitLab CI/CD variables, I do want them to be shared in generated projects pipelines, and afaik that is the intended use for vars in GitLab CI/CD. But let's leave that, cause that's not the topic of my question.  
I'm using `template_file` instead of `local_file` because I'm creating multiple files with similar content, which I haven't put much thought into yet. Do you think that making the same with `local_file` will make this operation easier?

Comment: I got to agree with @Patrick this screams anti-pattern, feels like you are applying a Model View Controller (MVC) design pattern to terraform code, all your templates are on a module an you pass those to other modules; that is not a design I would pick for terraform ... are you just experimenting with modules see what is possible or is this a real world use case? ... probably best to add all your code (or a minimal example) to GitHub where we can look at this design.

Comment: Yes, it would be easier with `local_file` over rendering your template and passing it, because you could loop over the files that were present as artifacts. That having been said, if this is something you really want to do, you'd be better off using a `for_each` block within the parent configuration. Instead of trying to loop within one module invocation (and thus running into the fact that outputs can't work in that situation), you'd invoke the module many times - one for each file you produced. Then you'd use for each chaining for your k8s deployment.

Comment: "all your templates are on a module and you pass those to other modules" - yep, I'm  trying to keep module-related data within the module, means if the kubeconfigs are generated in ./kubernetes and then used/saved as vars in ./gitlab module, I was hoping it would be possible that way (but that might have been wrong assumption). 
It's a real use case, so I'm actively working on the solution. Will try the approach with `local_file-s` first but prepare the repository later on.

Thank you for the input so far!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @patric input from comments, I've switched the "template_file" to "local_file" and this solved my problem.

New form:

```
resource "local_file" "kubeconfigs" {
  count    = length(var.namespaces)
  filename = "${var.namespaces[count.index].name}_kubeconfig"

  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/kubeconfig.tpl", {
    ...
  })
}

output "generated_kubeconfigs" {
  value = local_file.kubeconfigs
}
```

passing to GitLab module:

```
module "gitlab" {
  source = "./gitlab"
  kubeconfigs = concat(module.kubernetes_dev.generated_kubeconfigs,
                       module.kubernetes_stg.generated_kubeconfigs)
}
```

and using as:

```
resource "gitlab_group_variable" "group_variables_kubeconfigs" {
  count = length(var.kubeconfigs)
  value = base64encode(var.kubeconfigs[count.index].content)
  ...
}
```